How to allow concurrent reads for read only transactions in Spring?
To give some background about my question, I'm using Spring and Hibernate and I have an entity with multiple @OneToMany relationships. Something like this:
class EntityA {

    @Id
    val id: Long

    @OneToMany
    val listB: List<EntityB>

    @OneToMany
    val listC: List<EntityC>
}

My initial problem was infamous N+1 problem, but I was able to solve it by following the instructions from this article. To do so I had to create separate queries that would use a JOIN FETCH to cache the information from the related entities that could be used later without the use of a new query. To guarantee that I would use the same persistence context, I wrapped my method in a @Transactional(readOnly = true) annotation. Everything worked fine until I had to deal with multiple concurrent requests. I'm still not sure about what exactly happened, but as the requests were being completed one after the other, I suppose that each request was locking the table during the transaction. This is causing a huge delay for the response times.
What could be the possible solutions for this problem? Is my assumption of a transactional problem correct? Or is it something else?
