How does transactions work from a read-only perspective in Spring JPA + Hibernate?
Before the actual question, let me give some background: Recently I stumbled upon a N+1 problem which according to this article written by Vlad Mihalcea it could be solved by prefetching the entities from the relationships within the same persistence context. Indeed it solved the N+1 problem (to a fixed number of 10 queries). However, the performance was drastically decreased after this implementation, and I'm still trying to figure out why. Sometimes I would even get a timeout when trying to connect to the database with the error Unable to acquire JDBC Connection.
So, my question is: what happens behind the scenes when I use @Transactional(readOnly=true) in a method? Does it create a lock while the method is running? If so, what could I do to guarantee that I'm in the same persistence context and therefore achieve what I want with the prefetch?
Anything that could point me in the direction of the actual problem would be very much appreciated.
Edit: I forgot to mention that the problem is mostly apparent when I have a large amount of concurrent requests. It seems like each request has to wait until the previous one has been finished. This is why I suspect that it could be a lock issue.

readOnly is just a hint, it garantuees nothing. As long as you are inside an @Transactional method you have the same persistence context. To fix performance issues increate the jdbc fetch size (for larger collections) and write a dedicated query with FETCH JOIN to get related entities and fields. Or even better write a query with a dedicated DTO which only retrieves what you need.

As a sidenote to the uninitiated you cannot write a join query that uses a DTO for the result. Last I checked anyway.

@M.Deinum I'm already usingFETCH JOIN in my queries for each of the relationships. However, I feel that because of @Transaction I have trouble with concurrent requests. It seems like each request has to wait all 10 queries from the previous transaction before it can start executing. Is there a particular reason for that? Can I keep the persistence context without using @Transaction?

Depending on how many concurrent transactions you have running and how long they take your connection pool might be depleted. Also if you are doing weird things yourself (or have wrongly configured hibernate) you might end up with other session being opened. If you already have a query with FETCH JOIN why do  you have 10 of those instead of a single query? Judging from the error you get you are doing strange things in your code leading to connection starvation. SO post some code, configuration etc. you are using.

@M.Deinum I have an entity with some @OneToMany relationships, and I have an endpoint to return a list of those entities. By using one query to JOIN FETCH each relationship, by the end I'd have all of them prefetched in my persistence context, not leading to a N+1 when mapping it to my DTO. I didn't post any code here because I didn't think it was relevant because at this point I just want to understand the logic behind the scenes here. But about the connection pool being depleted, does each transaction has to be executed entirely before the next one?

@M.Deinum I posted another question with a little bit of code a while ago, but didn't have any answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79295541/how-to-allow-concurrent-reads-for-read-only-transactions-in-spring

That contains far too little information. Just an entity, not how you retrieve, what queries you execute etc. Also asking the same question again instead of editing and providing new information is consideren not so nice.

@M.Deinum Understood, I'll try to provide some useful information. Thanks for the advice.
